# Is there anyway to configure a https proxy on an android phone to make all requests go through one nginx server?

Tags: android, ssl, nginx, http-proxy

I try to use nginx as a https proxy for android phone, nginx config is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate "trust-chain.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "key.pem";
    location / {
        proxy_pass   https://127.0.0.1:9000/;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    ......
```

I use this command to generate ssl certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365
```

then I upload `cert.pem` to `https://certificatechain.io/` to generate the intermediate certificate `trust-chain.crt`. And I install this `trust-chain.crt` on android phone. Then I modify the http proxy on android wifi settings as follows:

```
 Proxy: Manual
 host: xx.xx.xx.xx
 port 80
```

I can see those "CONNECT xx.xx.xx.xx:443" requests on nginx log, but they are all failed with 400 HTTP code. Where am I doing it wrong?